# How to get a full width background on mobile?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, horizontal-scrolling

I'm using a full-width background on my website that expands outside the div container, cf. http://www.csselectronics.com/ (near the end).

This works fine on desktop, though I struggle to replicate the effect on mobile. I'm using two different CSS styles, loaded via a screen-width based setup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="http://canlogger1000.csselectronics.com/lightbox/FullWidth_Mobile_v17.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 601px)" href="http://canlogger1000.csselectronics.com/lightbox/FullWidth_Big.css">
```

The problem is with the mobile version; as you can see if viewing the page on mobile, the background color does not stretch outside the container to cover 100% of the visible width. I've tried many things, but I always encounter the issue that I expand the view so that the user can scroll horizontally which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the block on the bottom with "Powerful, Simple, Affordable" etc?

There's no easy way to do it without changing the HTML, unless you add a `width: 120%` or something along those lines to force the block to overflow the container but that would cause horizontal scrolling as you mentioned.

A much easier way would be if you took the block out of the regular container, and used a new HTML block for it.

So it'll be, (rough example)

```
<div class="container>
// Your regular content here
</div>

//In this grey block, make it width 100% and add the content you want
<div class="grey-block">
//So the content inside will still be aligned with the rest of the page
<div class="container">
</div>
</div>

//Continue with the rest of the page
<div class="container>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I would like to do this, but unfortunately I'm working on a e-com platform where that level of choice is not available. I.e. I'm forced to work within the basic div container already put in place. I'm not sure if there's anything that can be done in that case?

Comment: Does the e-com platform allow Javascript/jQuery code to be added in?

If it does you can just detach the block and play around with the DOM to add it back in.